# Запись значений в столбик в excel

Tags: java, list, filestream, apache-poi

Есть структура

```
public List<List<String>> finishFile = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

public List<List<String>> getFinishFile() {
    return finishFile;
}

public void setFinishFile(List<List<String>> finishFile) {
    this.finishFile.addAll(finishFile);
}
```

у меня в нее собираются данные в процессе работы из разных файлов. мне нужно вывести эти данные в файл эксель, так чтобы данные располагались по столбцам. У меня получается только по строкам, и как переделать на столбцы я не могу понять. буду благодарен за помощь.

что я хочу в итоге? - 
у меня есть есть на входе структура список списков строк, где допустим 5 списков по 10 строк в каждом. собственно мне нужно получить таблицу из 5 столбцов по 10 строк в каждом.
вот мое решение для вывода. оно увы не верное.

```
public void write(String PATH) {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        for (List<String> row1 : getFinishFile()) {
            cell.setCellValue(row1.get(0));
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Возникает где-то ошибка или просто вывод в файле не удовлетворяет вашим требованиям?

Comment: да выводится все в виде длинных строк. не по столбцам.

Comment: Может быть я что-то упускаю, но... вопрос: для чего вы передаете методу путь к одному файлу, если при этом данные вы получаете из List'а, а записываете их в совершенно другой файл?

Comment: ну как я понимаю  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx"); я таким образом указываю файл куда будет все записанно.

Comment: В таком случае у вас в конце должно быть не `new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");`, а `new FileOutputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");`.

Comment: ну да уже понял это, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void write(String PATH) {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCounter = 0;              
        for (List<String> row1 : getFinishFile()) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter++);
            int columnCounter = 0;
            for (String s : row1) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCounter++);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); 
                cell.setCellValue(s); 
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: попробовал, почему то пустой файл на выходе.

Comment: Уверены, что ваш List<List<String>> заполнен?

Comment: да конечно. я как раз в дебаге сижу.

Comment: Можете написать мне на почту rdanilov.dev@gmail.com, посмотрим, в чем проблема

Comment: спасибо! сейчас напишу.

Comment: отбой) в последней строке путь PATH + забыл указать) боже)) но все ок выводит по столбцам))

Comment: Отлично) Успехов вам)